# How do i specify a version range for Maven dependency plugin get on command line

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3

I'm trying to use the maven dependency plugin to get an artifact in a specific version range. I need to do this on the command line (or in a script)

Here is what i tried:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact="junit:junit:[4.0,4.11)"
```

However, the range is apparently not recognized as such. Maven tries and fails to download an artifact with the literal version of *[4.0.0,4.11.0)*.

I guess i am using the wrong syntax and/or are not escaping correctly.

How can i get maven to *get* the artifact with the highest version fitting the specified version range?

Error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) junit:junit:jar:[4.0,4.11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version ranges are not supported for this goal:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-88

I get:

```
Failed to retrieve POM for junit:junit:jar:[4.0,4.11): Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:[4.0,4.11) from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Illegal character in path at index 49: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/[4.0,4.11)/junit-[4.0,4.11).pom
```

So the range is not parsed.

Not sure what's an alternative that does the exact same thing :/

the versions plugin allows to resolve ranges http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/resolve-ranges-mojo.html but only within a pom.xml - one would need to create a fake pom.xml - use this plugin to resolve the version and then get that out of the created pom - there is hopefully a better way...

Answer (score 1):

To work around a similar situation I did

```
   <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.group.name</groupId>
                <artifactId>name-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>[x,]</version> <!-- use any range -->
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.group.name</groupId>
                <artifactId>name-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- specify no version -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- any config -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
....
```

The above works however you get a WARNING about the missing version in the plugin, so potentially this may error out in future Maven version - as per the warning

Comment: Question mentions version of dependencies not version of plugin

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround using maven-assembly-plugin.  It unpacks the content of a zip dependency with a version range to the directory `super/parent`.

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-stuff</artifactId>
    <type>zip</type>
    <version>(,2)</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>...</id>
          <phase>...</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <attach>false</attach>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <finalName>parent</finalName>
            <formats>
              <format>dir</format>
            </formats>
            <outputDirectory>super</outputDirectory>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

assembly.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.2.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.2.0
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.2.0.xsd">
  <id>...</id>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <includes>
        <include>com.example:my-stuff:zip</include>
      </includes>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```